# How can i making an Opencart Events and trigger in catalog, but have its action in admin?

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to add an event in opencart 2.3.0.2, 
my event trigger is in catalog (Front End) and my action is in admin.
But event does not work.
This is my code:

```
$this->model_extension_event->addEvent('repository_Output', 'api/order/history/after', 
      'admin/controller/extension/repository/output/exitAfterSell');
```

I have a question, is this naturally impossible in opencart, or I have mistake in my code?

this code doesn't work too:

```
$this->model_extension_event->addEvent('repository_Output', 'api/order/history/after', 
      'admin/extension/repository/output/exitAfterSell');
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work?"  The even is triggered and then what happens?

Comment: it mean trigger work, but action doesn't work, in another say, when trigger and action both in catalog or both in admin, event work, but if one is in catalog and another is in admin, not work!